# Número de processadores no Hyper-V

Tags: windows, servidor, virtualhost, hyper-v

Tenho um servidor Windows Server 2003 virtualizado com Hyper-V.

Configurei a opção "números de processadores lógicos" para 4.

No Windows, ele aparece na lista de gerenciamento de dispositivos 4 CPUs. Porém no gerenciador de tarefas do Windows, no histórico de uso de CPU só aparece 1 gráfico.

As dúvidas são:

1. Está rodando com os 4 CPUs ou está rodando somente com 1 CPU?
2. Se estiver rodando somente com 1, como faço para rodar com os 4?

Observações:

- Tenho outra máquina igual, e virtualizei com VMware e aparecem os 4 CPUs no gráfico.
- Fisicamente, o *hardware* possui somente 1 *socket*, 1 processador com 4 núcleos e 4 *threads*.

Comment: li na central de ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic que o foco é "programação" acho que a minha dúvida é sim enquadrada como "programação de servidores" o SO inglês abrange configurações de servidores tipo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862967/zabbix-jmx-tomcat-monitoring seria bom se tivéssemos um conteúdo desses em portugues, porque a area onde atua um profissional de programação geralmente atua um profissional  que gerencia os servidores dos programadores, e acredite, este profissional também tem dúvidas e também precisa de ajuda.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2640/perguntas-referente-a-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-servidores

Comment: @MaisonSakamoto no `Task Manager`, botão direito sobre o gráfico do *CPU*, escolha Alterar gráfico para e depois escolha Processadores Lógicos. Por defeito, o *WinSrv* apresenta o gráfico de utilização geral do *CPU* invés de apresentar um gráfico por *thread*.

Comment: @Omni é S.O. Windows Server 2003, não achei essa opção de alterar o gráfico, clico com o botão direito e não me aparece nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este caso resolvi reiniciando o servidor hyper-v, já tinha reiniciado a maquina virtual e não tinha resolvido, mas após reiniciar o servidor hyper-v apareceu certinho os 4 cpu